# Automapper: Hydrate int? based on conditions

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-2

I have the following code:

```
[Test]
public void ConditionalMapping()
{
    var src = new Sample1 {Age = 1, Number = null};
    var dest = new Sample2 {Age = null, Number = 1};

    Hydrate(src, dest, false);

    Assert.That(dest.Age, Is.EqualTo(1));
    Assert.That(dest.Number, Is.EqualTo(1));

    src = new Sample1 {Age = null, Number = 1};
    dest = new Sample2 {Age = 1, Number = null};

    Hydrate(src, dest, true);

    Assert.That(dest.Age, Is.Null);
    Assert.That(dest.Number, Is.EqualTo(1));
}

public void Hydrate(Sample1 src, Sample2 dest, bool allowOverride)
{
    if (!dest.Age.HasValue || allowOverride)
        dest.Age = src.Age;

    if (!dest.Number.HasValue || allowOverride)
        dest.Number = src.Number;
}

public class Sample1
{
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    public int? Number { get; set; }
}

public class Sample2
{
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    public int? Number { get; set; }
}
```

Which basically hydrates an `int?` if the value is `null` unless `allowOverride = true`, in which it will hydrate the value without checking the value of the field.

How would I go about doing this in Automapper?

I know that you can use .Condition() as shown here:

[Automapper's condition gets ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012725/automappers-condition-gets-ignored)

But I couldn't figure out how to:

1. Apply the logic based on `int?` without defining it one by one.
2. Include the `allowOverride` boolean to the Mapper.

Answer (score 0):

I may have found a potential solution for you - depending on how you want the `allowOverride` flag to work.

If you want the flag to operate the same for all mappings you can create a `TypeConverter` as follows

```cs
public class NullableIntConverter : ITypeConverter<int?, int?>
{
    private bool AllowOverrides { get; set;}

    public NullableIntConverter(bool allowOverrides)
    {
        AllowOverrides = allowOverrides;
    }

    public int? Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var source = context.SourceValue as int?;
        var destination = context.DestinationValue as int?;
        if (destination.HasValue && !AllowOverrides)
            return destination;
        else
            return source;
    }
}
```

Initialise it like this:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<Sample1, Sample2>();
Mapper.CreateMap<int?, int?>().ConvertUsing(new NullableIntConverter(true));
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

It will now check the destination for a value, and override it as appropriate depending on your constructor argument.

---

**OR**

---

If you want to be able to configure it for each mapping specifically, then you could use a `ValueResolver` (note that this code could do with some extra validation):

```cs
public class NullableIntResolver : IValueResolver
{
    public bool AllowOverrides { get; set; }

    public NullableIntResolver(bool allowOverrides)
    {
        AllowOverrides = allowOverrides;
    }

    public ResolutionResult Resolve(ResolutionResult source)
    {
        // Add validation for source and destination types
        return source.New(
                   ResolveCore((int?) source.Value,
                               DestinationMemberValue(source.Context)),
                   typeof(int?));
    }

    public int? ResolveCore(int? source, int? destination)
    {
        if (destination.HasValue && !AllowOverrides)
            return destination;
        else
            return source;
    }

    private int? DestinationMemberValue(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var destObject = context.DestinationValue;
        var destMemberName = context.MemberName;
        return (int?) destObject
                          .GetType()
                          .GetProperty(destMemberName)
                          .GetValue(destObject, null);
    }
}
```

You can then initialise your mappings like this:

```cs
var allowOverrides = true;
Mapper.CreateMap<Sample1, Sample2>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Age,
               opt => opt.ResolveUsing<NullableIntResolver>()
               .FromMember(src => src.Age)
               .ConstructedBy(() => new NullableIntResolver(allowOverrides)))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Number,
               opt => opt.ResolveUsing<NullableIntResolver>()
               .FromMember(src => src.Number)
               .ConstructedBy(() => new NullableIntResolver(allowOverrides)));
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

Comment: I am going to give this a try and let you know.